# Do people that play instruments use sequencers?

Tags: production

I've been coming across videos lately where people have these step sequencers and they even use it for melody/harmony. Such as [volca bass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkiEgogSxe4). Why would people that can play a keyboard use such sequencers?

I kind of understand why people would use drum sequencers. But sequencers for melody/harmony? it got me wondering...

p.s when you plug in a keyboard midi controller into logic and record something, is that also considered sequencing? Because I don't mean that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would people that can play a keyboard use such sequencers?

- To be able to edit what they played without having to re-record it all again
- to be able to reassign the notes that they played to different instruments. If you just record the audio, it's very difficult to change the sound after the fact
- To be able to create musical parts that couldn't be physically played by the available instrumentalists
- To allow the musician to record a part, and then edit/shape it in real time by tweaking the sequence, or changing parameters

Comment: And: why not? It can be just another fun way of creating music.

Comment: @Draakhond definitely. A different process often gives you different results!

Comment: The question isn't "why would you use a sequencer?" it's "why would you use a hardware sequencer rather than just play it in like any rational human being?"

Comment: @Tetsujin you are right about what the question is, but i didn't know musicians are rational human beings.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be considered an answer - because the answer is going to be "some do, some don't"…

imnsho, anyone using one of those things to sequence entire tracks either has some deep-seated masochistic streak or just wants to be able to look 'cool' on youtube.

I once spent an entire night programming a bass line on an early 80s version of that thing [whilst everybody else in the studio went out to a restaurant & a gig] & wouldn't wish it on my worst enemy.

The track in question - it had to be programmed linearly, it couldn't be a series of repeats because of one tiny detail - the root is always over the kick drum, even when the kick goes to 16ths.